# Multipart files http request with Spring Rest Template arrives without the files

Tags: java, spring, httprequest, messaging, resttemplate

I have this client for sending multipart file http requests with Rest Template

```
    @Component
    public class RestTemplatePost {

        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        @PostConstruct
        public void prepareMessage() throws Exception {

            File file = new File("****");
            File file2 = new File("****");

            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

            MultiValueMap<String, Object> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();


            form.add("files", file);
            form.add("files", file2);
            form.add("usertoken", "test");
            form.add("sendTo", "test);
            form.add("subject", "test");
            form.add("content", "test");

            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(form, httpHeaders);

            String serverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/mails/send";

            List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
            httpMessageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
            httpMessageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

            restTemplate().setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters);


            restTemplate().postForEntity(serverUrl, requestEntity, String.class);


        }
}
```

Then I have this server side that should receive the request:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainConroller {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainConroller.class);
    @Autowired
    private MainService mainService;

    public MainConroller(MainService mainService) {
        this.mainService = mainService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/mails/send")
    public  void send(
            @RequestParam("usertoken") String usertoken,
            @RequestParam("sendTo") String sendTo,
            @RequestParam("subject") String subject,
            @RequestParam("content") String content,
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "files") List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles) {
        log.debug("{}, {}, {}, {}", usertoken, sendTo, subject, content);

        mainService.processMessage(usertoken, sendTo, subject, content, multipartFiles);

    }
}
```

When I send this request from the client side, everything arrives on the server side except the files.

The RequestParam files is empty after receiving the request.

**Update**
Message converters explicitly removed as recommended, nothing changed.

Comment: Remove the message converters (those are registered by default) and try again. Also shouldn't this be a `FileResource` instead of a `File`?

Comment: I have removed converters, nothing changed. It still doesn't work.

Comment: You have what? Removed the converts and `FileResource`?

Comment: Can't it be something else than a FileResource? There is barely any documentation on how to create that structure.

Comment: `new FileSystemResource(<your-path-here>);` ... Just use your IDE.

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past but sending from html form - fixed it by having 2 mappings and 2 forms one for the main form fields and 1 for the files, otherwise like you the receiving end wouldn't get the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No files are sent because there is no `HttpMessageConverter` capable of converting a `java.io.File`.
On the other hand, there is a [`ResourceHttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/ResourceHttpMessageConverter.html) which converts all kinds of [`Resource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html), including [`FileSystemResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html).

PS `FormHttpMessageConverter` is added by default when `RestTemplate` is created and `FormHttpMessageConverter` also uses it under the hood.